# Using gwt fx to fade one image into another

Tags: gwt

I am using gwt fx to fade an image using the code below.I was wondering if there was a way to make it fade one image into another.

```
Fade theFade = new Fade();
theFade.addEffectElement(image_1.getElement());
theFade.play()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably try adding addEffectCompletedHandler to theFade and kick off the next effect.

Comment: I got it working by using two image elements one on top of the other fading one in and one out and doing some updates with the complete handler cheers.